# Can we get only amazon prime product using Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I have searched how to use Amazon Product Advertising API and now I am able to search different product using Amazon Product Advertising API and it is working fine.

But as I know we can get only amazon prime product from our account and when I login with amazon account using amazon site and search any product I found only amazon prime product.

But when I am trying to get amazon product using Amazon Product Advertising API with my security id etc Amazon Product Advertising API give us all product in search but I need only prime product list when I search with Amazon Product Advertising API.

Is it possible?

Comment: By Amazon API you are referring to the Product Advertising API?

Comment: i don't know about this i have just used amazon api as amazon developer can you please send us more detail for Product Advertising API if you know anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a link to the "amazon api" that you are using.

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: Can you tell me if i need to use other link for only prime product ?

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: check `IsEligibleForPrime` [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use this response groups Offers/Offer/OfferListing and search for IsEligibleForPrime attribute, this is used to know in this offer is primer eligible or not

Answer (score 0):

At this point there is no way to tell if a product is prime available.

Answer (score 0):

you an tell if product is prime by checking IsEligibleForPrime in the OfferListing response group.