# Detect whether or not a customer has an Amazon Prime membership with the Amazon API

Tags: types, request, response, amazon-product-api

I am trying to figure out a way to use the Amazon API to detect whether or not a customer has an Amazon Prime membership - according to the [customer information API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/customer_info/CustomerInfo_GetCustomersForCustomerId.html) - this is what a response looks like when you look up a customer:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetCustomersForCustomerIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/CustomerInformation/2014-03-01">
  <GetCustomersForCustomerIdResult>
    <CustomerList>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerId>AQA0987654321</CustomerId>
        <ShippingAddressList>
          <ShippingAddress>
            <IsDefaultAddress>true</IsDefaultAddress>
            <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
            <AddressLine1>12345 Example Ave</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Apt 12345</AddressLine2>
            <City>Seattle</City>
            <StateOrRegion>WA</StateOrRegion>
            <PostalCode>98121</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          </ShippingAddress>
        </ShippingAddressList>
        <PrimaryContactInfo>
          <Email>JohnDoe@customeremail.com</Email>
          <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
        </PrimaryContactInfo>
        <AccountType>NORMAL</AccountType>
        <AssociatedMarketplaces>
          <MarketplaceDomain>
            <DomainName>MyWebstoreName.com</DomainName>
            <AssociatedOn>2012-07-18T00:00:00Z</AssociatedOn>
            <LastUpdatedOn>2012-07-18T17:21:16Z</LastUpdatedOn>
          </MarketplaceDomain>
        </AssociatedMarketplaces>
      </Customer>
    </CustomerList>
    <NextToken>QVYyVTY5NUVaQzBDWHw0ODEXAMPLECB8IHw1OTM0MDZ8IHwwLDJ8</NextToken>
    <MoreResultsAvailable>true</MoreResultsAvailable>
  </GetCustomersForCustomerIdResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>8547a35c-8e70-11EXAMPLE-5bf2881764d8</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetCustomersForCustomerIdResponse>
```

I have looked at what all the datatypes mean (see the above link) - and none of them output any information about whether or not the customer has an Amazon Prime membership.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: If you search the site for "Prime," the only result pertains to items. It would seem you can't tell who has Prime and who doesn't.

Comment: As of a few months ago, you [can't even tell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23700643/632736) if items are Prime eligible.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer - so basically if I am setting up a webstore "off-amazon" and I want to see if I can allow the customer to use Amazon Prime shipping rates (as they should be able to according to Fulfillment by Amazon, which is the service I am using) - there is simply no way to do it?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer saw ur link - thats crazy - I guess I can't integrate Amazon Prime stuff then...

Comment: Sorry man. I've been in your shoes and it sucks not having the data you need exposed through the official APIs. Best of luck in achieving your goal though.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer yah - in messing around with these API's I've learned that Amazon really doesn't have their sh*t together haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this isn't possible. The API docs only mention Prime in the scope of items, not consumers. You can't determine if a customer is a Prime subscriber, and you [can't even determine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700643/632736) if items are Prime eligible.

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case ? I can't find any mention of it in the online docs, but it seems crazy that we *still* can't access this information.